# Update Datalist in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net

I've two updatepanel in the same page.
In one, there is a datalist while in other there is a modal popup.
In modal popup I have a Save button that update datalist's data. In effect Save button work correctly and data are updated but to see updated data in datalist I must do a postback while I would that Save button occur an asyncpostback and datalist show me updated data after Save Button' Click.

I do this in updatepanel of modalpopup:

```
<Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

P.S Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same thing for the UpdatePanel you want to update (that contains the DataList):

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Since a child of the UpdatePanel isn't triggering the postback, it doesn't know to refresh, telling it explicitly that when `btnSave` is clicked it should do so should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks,Now work but I have another thing to ask you. In my modal popup I have some textbox that allow user to update data but when I insert a value in a textbox and then click Save button in datalist I see my data repeat over and over again with more comma.

For example.. if I insert Pippo.. then in datalist I see ,,Pippo,Pippo Why?

Comment: @Ivan90 - What are you using for the modal?  I remember seeing this issue with a particular type of modal a while back, probably the same thing.

Comment: Mhh... I'm using ModalPopupExtender. I can't resolve this problem. Probably the problem are the properties updatemode and childrenastriggers of two update panel!

Comment: @Ivan90 - It seems this is an issue with the toolkit, some users on here rolled back to the May release to resolve the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588026/modalpopupextender-and-commas-appearing-in-my-textbox-asp-net/1753497#1753497

Answer (score 0):

In you btnSave event handler you can force the datalist panel to update like this:

```
public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save logic
    pnlDataList.Update();
}
```