# After Download zip file datalist is not Bind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

Below is my code on button search i need to bind my grid and download zip file problem is there zip file is download but my grid is not bind function is called but datalist is not bind

```
Private Sub BindGrid()
    SQL = "Select JameatID,JamaatID,MadrassahID, JameatName,JamaatName,MadrassahName,StudentID,ClassID,DIvisionName,FullName,datediff (year ,DOB,getdate() )as Age  from vwstudent vw LEFT OUTER JOIN CMaster cm ON vw.ClassID =cm.CMID AND MasterName ='ClassID'  where 1=1   order by JameatName,JamaatName,MadrassahName,cm.OrderId "
    Dim ds As New dataset
    ds = gc.GetDataToListBinder(SQL)
    DListPhotoInfo.DataSource = ds 
    DListPhotoInfo.DataBind()

End Sub

Private Sub DownloadImage(ByVal EJID As String)
    Dim DS As Data.DataSet
    Dim tmpZipFile As String
    tmpZipFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName
    Dim zipFile As New GraficaliZip(tmpZipFile)
    zipFile.CreateZipFile()
    Dim strID() As String = Split(EJID.Trim, ",")
    For i As Integer = 0 To strID.Length - 1
         If ImageExist(strID(i).Trim) = True Then
             zipFile.PutFile(Server.MapPath(".") & _
                             "\Photo\" & strID(i).Trim & _
                             ".jpg", strID(i).Trim & ".jpg")
         End If
     Next
       BindGrid() ///from here i am binding grid
     zipFile.SaveFile()
     gc.DownLoadFileFromServer("", tmpZipFile & ".zip", "Photo.zip")
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click


    DownloadImage("20312059,20313178")
    PnlGrid.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you also include the code for your `BindGrid()` function?

Comment: i update my code for bindgrid plz refer

Comment: May be some other code is spoiling the DataList. So...

Try putting breakpoint @ the last line of `BindGrid()` method. Confirm the data fetched and bind properly to the DataList. Then move forward step by step to check which part of the code is disturbing the DataList after it has been bind properly.

Answer (score 1):

Call your BindGrid() method inside of !IsPostBack in pageLoad event

For

```
Page_load()
{
 if(!IsPostBack)
 {
 BindGrid()
 }    
}
```

and also you need to call your  BindGrid() method in download button click event

```
Private Sub DownloadImage(ByVal EJID As String)
    Dim DS As Data.DataSet
    Dim tmpZipFile As String
    tmpZipFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName
    Dim zipFile As New GraficaliZip(tmpZipFile)
    zipFile.CreateZipFile()
    Dim strID() As String = Split(EJID.Trim, ",")
    For i As Integer = 0 To strID.Length - 1
         If ImageExist(strID(i).Trim) = True Then
             zipFile.PutFile(Server.MapPath(".") & _
                             "\Photo\" & strID(i).Trim & _
                             ".jpg", strID(i).Trim & ".jpg")
         End If
     Next
     zipFile.SaveFile()
     gc.DownLoadFileFromServer("", tmpZipFile & ".zip", "Photo.zip")
 **BindGrid()**
End Sub
```

**Update**:

first call download method ,then call binding method when your search button on-click

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click


    DownloadImage("20312059,20313178")
 **BindGrid()**
    PnlGrid.Visible = True
End Sub
```

**Edit :**
If you used update panel , then

Call `UpdatePanelID.Update()` after call `BindGrid`()

- When the `UpdatePanel` control is nested inside another `UpdatePanel` control and the parent panel is updated.

**More problems :**

Look this link's

http://forums.asp.net/t/1605207.aspx

[Update Datalist in UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347934/update-datalist-in-updatepanel)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1320236.aspx/1?update+panel+doesnot+refresh+the+datalist+control+for+first+time

Comment: please one more time see my answer .

Comment: How to update datalist after download zip file..update panel also not refresh my datalist.

Comment: malummaaat nahi Datalist not refresh

Comment: need help to refresh my datalist

Comment: DownloadImage("20312059,20313178")
BindGrid()
PnlGrid.Visible = True                                            I am doing same but not work

Comment: i am edit my code please help.I am calling bindgrid function download function bt same problem bindgrid function call but datalist not bind

Comment: did you used Update Panel ?

Comment: Update Panel gives me javascript error when UpdatePanel.Update

Comment: this error give me when i update panel code is added then   Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'PK'.

Comment: See my answer. and see the links